# PHP - detect STDIO input

Tags: php, stdio

What I want is being able to *optionally* pipe STDIO to a PHP script. If not, it'll take input from a file instead. So sometimes I'll simply run the script, other times I'll do something like

```
grep text logfile | php parseLog.php
```

I have a loop very much like this and it works fine when STDIO exists:

```
while (FALSE !== ($line = fgets(STDIN)))
{
        $customLogArr[]=$line;
}
```

When there's no STDIO though it halts waiting for some, it doesn't even enter the loop.

What I'd like to do is be able to detect *if* I have STDIO input or not. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(FALSE !== ftell(STDIN))
{
    while (FALSE !== ($line = fgets(STDIN)))
    {
        $customLogArr[]=$line;
    }
}
```

For STDIN, if nothing can be read, `ftell()` will return false.

Comment: Last time I checked STDIN position never zeroed on read from STDIN and it was always a non-negative integer so `ftell` always returns `integer`.

Comment: @DeDee    Yes,you are right.  So false only mean No STDIN for current process.

Comment: Correct, until STDIN is closed.

Comment: php7 @ version 7 `PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )` seems to complain there is no STDIN defined. `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN' in - on line 3`

Answer (score 3):

Using `posix_isatty()` function might be a little simpler.

- [posix_isatty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-isatty.php) | Manual @ PHP.net

```php
<?php

/**
 * parseLog.php
 */

echo (posix_isatty(STDIN)) ? 'no stdin' . PHP_EOL : file_get_contents('php://stdin');
```

```
$ echo 'foo' > ./logfile.txt

$ cat logfile.txt | php parseLog.php
foo

$ php parseLog.php
no stdin
```

`posix_isatty(STDIN)` determines if the `STDIN` is open AND connected to a terminal. Thus, while receiving data from the `STDIN`, it will return `false`.

- REF: https://qiita.com/m_norii/items/cd2d66e5a82c11cac758 @ Qiita (in Japanese)

Answer (score 2):

looks like something has changed or none of these answers were ever correct. You cannot simply `ftell(STDIN)` to see if there is data passed from `STDIN`

```
<?php

$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
var_dump(ftell($stdin));
```

**outputs**

```
-:4:
bool(false)
```

This is from `php -v` with output

```
PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

when I try to use STDIN constant I get

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN' in - on line 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? Forgive me if I misunderstood, this should not hold you when there's no input on STDIN.

```
stream_set_blocking(STDIN, 1);

function CheckSTDIN() {
    $read = array(STDIN);
    $wrte = NULL;
    $expt = NULL;
    $a = stream_select($read, $wrte, $expt, 0);
    if ($a && in_array(STDIN, $read)) {
        // you can read from STDIN now, it'll only be available if there is anything in STDIN
        // you can return the value or pass it to global or class variable
        return fread(STDIN, 255); // set your desired string length
    } else return false;
}

while (FALSE !== ($line = CheckSTDIN())) {
        $customLogArr[]=$line;
}
```

Comment: Strange it does not work for you, I extracted it from my OOP project for which it works the way I described.

Comment: I reran, yes but: `fread() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given`

Comment: Oh, I assumed second one is some default, I use `1` in my case, it's an example though of how the stream content can be retrieved. EDIT: fixed `fread`.

Comment: @ErickRobertson In the comment above I said I extracted it from my own project. It was a Windows Apache project. It sure worked.

Comment: I don't have Apache.  I just have Windows.  It doesn't work on Windows.  You need either Apache or Linux.

Comment: @ErickRobertson Irrelevant, Apache provides web server environment. The above code worked in PHP CLI on windows 7. To be honest I don't know why I mentioned Apache at all. You do know you need PHP CLI, right?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a script like this:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php                                                              
<?php                                                                           
                                                                                
$fhandle = fopen("php://stdin", 'r');                                           
$stdinData = ftell($fhandle) === false // strict comparison required                             
    ? null                                                                      
    : stream_get_contents($fhandle);                                            
var_dump($stdinData);
```

The sript outputs this when no `stdin` data provided:

```
$ ./test.php 
NULL
```

The sript outputs this when `stdin` data provided:

```
$ ./test.php < ./test.php 
string(173) "#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$fhandle = fopen("php://stdin", 'r');
$stdinData = ftell($fhandle) === false // strict comparison required
    ? null
    : stream_get_contents($fhandle);
var_dump($stdinData);
"
```

The important part is to use strict comparison (`===`) as `ftell` returns pointer position that has a value of `0` in case the handle has just been initialized.

For PHP 7.3 and earlier slightly different approach has to be utilized:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

stream_set_blocking(STDIN, 0);
$stdinData = ftell(STDIN) === false // strict comparison required
    ? null
    : stream_get_contents(STDIN);
var_dump($stdinData);
```

Answer (score -1):

The above solution didn't work for me. This is one that works.

```
if ($args = stream_get_contents(fopen("php://stdin", "r"))) {

    var_dump($args);

} else {
    echo 'No input';
}
```

Note: This will read the data piped to the script as a string: echo "Hello World" | php test.php will output string(12) "Hello World" (+ the new line at the end...) So you need to further process the data to an array if that is required. explode() seems to be a simple approach.

Comment: But it hangs when nothing is one STDIN.  That's what OP is trying to get around.

Comment: Correct, this won't work when there's no STDIN unfortunately. I wish. :)

Comment: The problem is trying to get contents without `ftell($resource)` first. Most of the code on this page works if you just know what you are doing and why.